# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlite, schema

I'm unable to fix this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: event_entries (SQL:
>   select * from "event_entries")

I have looked at other similar questions but no luck.

I am using sqlite. I can not find any reference to the table in question in my code or through command line. I have done migration rollback, reset and refresh, re seeded, and finally tried adding this code:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('event_entries')) {
           Schema::drop('event_entries');
```

...to the events table migration. But no success and I have no clue what to try next.

In tinker it shows:

```
DB::select('select * from sqlite_master where type="table"')
=> [
     {#746
       +"type": "table",
       +"name": "migrations",
       +"tbl_name": "migrations",
       +"rootpage": "2",
       +"sql": "CREATE TABLE "migrations" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "migration" varchar not null, "batch" integer not null)",
     },
     {#748
       +"type": "table",
       +"name": "sqlite_sequence",
       +"tbl_name": "sqlite_sequence",
       +"rootpage": "3",
       +"sql": "CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)",
     },
     {#749
       +"type": "table",
       +"name": "users",
       +"tbl_name": "users",
       +"rootpage": "4",
       +"sql": "CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "name" varchar not null, "email" varchar not null, "password" varchar not null, "remember_token" varchar null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null)",
     },
     {#750
       +"type": "table",
       +"name": "password_resets",
       +"tbl_name": "password_resets",
       +"rootpage": "6",
       +"sql": "CREATE TABLE "password_resets" ("email" varchar not null, "token" varchar not null, "created_at" datetime null)",
     },
     {#751
       +"type": "table",
       +"name": "events_table",
       +"tbl_name": "events_table",
       +"rootpage": "8",
       +"sql": "CREATE TABLE "events_table" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "title" varchar not null, "address" varchar not null, "description" varchar not null, "lat" varchar not null, "lng" varchar not null, "event_date" datetime not null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null)",
     },
```

Migrate status:

+------+------------------------------------------------+

| Ran? | Migration                                      |

+------+------------------------------------------------+

| Y    | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table           |

| Y    | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table |

| Y    | 2018_01_08_174209_create_events_table          |

Comment: Do it on a fresh DB. Same result?

Comment: you mean when migrating does the migration says `event_entries` migrated ?

Comment: also could you add your code for the event_entries migration ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its happening because I renamed the schema. I put the schema name back to original name and did the migrate reset and then migrate, and its back up and running. Reason I renamed it is cause for a different question.

Answer (score 0):

For this error you can do php artisan migrate. Then try your form again

Comment: I resolved it thanks everyone